# Что такое ctx в библиотеке discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

Постоянно замечаю в дискорд ботах атрибут ctx, да и сам его частенько использую, но все равно до конца не понял что это такое, какие у него есть методы кроме ctx.send()

Помогите найти документацию по этому атрибуту, или перечислите все его методы!

Answer (score 5):

`ctx` — это сокращение от слова `context`.

Обычно эта переменная ссылается на [одноимённый класс](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context), который имеет следующие атрибуты:

```py
['args', 'author', 'bot', 'channel', 'cog', 'command', 'command_failed', 'guild', 'invoked_parents', 'invoked_subcommand', 'invoked_with', 'kwargs', 'me', 'message', 'prefix', 'subcommand_passed', 'valid', 'voice_client']
```

и методы:

```py
['fetch_message', 'history', 'invoke', 'pins', 'reinvoke', 'reply', 'send', 'send_help', 'trigger_typing', 'typing']
```

---

Также посмотреть все атрибуты и методы класса можно передав объект стандартной функции [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir):

```py
print(dir(ctx))
```

Ещё советую обратить внимание на функцию [`help`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help).